# iOS uisearchviewcontroller use for web service

Tags: ios, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using UISearchDisplayController in my tableview. It search perfectly in an array. But What should I do if when I have to fetch data from web service?

Comment: Not clear question. Please specify me: You want get data from web service, depends on text inputed in search field. And display it on tableview. Correct?

Comment: ya. exactly .you are right.

Answer (score 1):

1. Implement your class for API interaction. 
   How to:

   - http://www.raywenderlich.com/51127/nsurlsession-tutorial - Using default URLSession
     OR
   - http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/working-with-nsurlsession-afnetworking-20--mobile-22651 - Third-party library. (easier for first use)
2. In your UITableViewController implement searchbar delegate event, on which you want to send request. For example:

   ```
         - (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar;
   ```

In this method call your API request.

3. In call back from request parse data
   How to:

   - https://www.safaribooksonline.com/blog/2013/03/06/parsing-json-in-objective-c-using-nsjsonserialization/ - JSON
     OR
   - http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/xml-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-choose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project - XML
4. Then set your new datasource array from parsed data and call [tableView reloadData].

P.S.: If it not clear. Mail me, I'll post sample project here.